# Как в JS проверить содержит ли строка пробелы?

Tags: javascript

есть переменная str типа String.
Как проверить содержит ли переменная пробелы

Пример:
если `str == "text text"`
возвращаем true

если `str == "texttext"`
возвращаем false

Comment: Первая ссылка в гугле https://otus.ru/nest/post/1453/#:~:text=%D0%94%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%2C%20%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8,%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%2C%20%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%2D1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать [string.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

```js
console.log("text text".includes(' '));
console.log("texttext".includes(' '));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
str = 'text text'
console.info(/\s/.test(str))
```